# Click through transparent form

Tags: delphi, transparent

I have a semi transparent fullscreen form and I need can control my computer over this form.

Actualy we need red screen filter on computer for observing the sky, but we don't want to use something like red plexiglass.

I tried Windows API's (Monitor Configuration Functions) 
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd692964(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd692964%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
but I can't do it.
I did transparent form like red filter (everything seems Red and Black tones), but I can't control computer over my form. Anybody help me about that ?

Answer (score 13):

Create a new VCL project. In the properties of the main form, set `Color` to `clRed`, `AlphaBlend` to `true`, `AlphaBlendValue` to `127`, `WindowState` to `wsMaximized`, `FormStyle` to `fsStayOnTop`, and add the following code:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  private
  protected
    procedure CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams); override;

...

procedure TForm1.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited;
  Params.ExStyle := Params.ExStyle or WS_EX_LAYERED or WS_EX_TRANSPARENT;
end;
```

([Sample video](http://privat.rejbrand.se/transplayer.mp4), [Sample compiled EXE](http://privat.rejbrand.se/transplayer.exe), [Source](http://privat.rejbrand.se/transplayer.zip))

Comment: Yeah, I know. :-) You're not responsible for PEBKAC issues. :D Cleaning up noise I added above. I'll delete this too in a few minutes.