# A form that does not handle mouse and keyboard event

Tags: delphi, keyboard, event-handling, mouse

I want to make a form in Delphi that does not handle mouse and keyboard events and pass them to the window below itself. How can I do this?

Comment: Given a 'form', what exactly is 'the window below it'? Perhaps you mean something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11809973/click-through-transparent-form?

Comment: Anything, I want to make a glass covering everything on desktop. (FormAlpha=150)

Comment: @Andreas Rejbrand Thanks, That's exactly what I need. Post your answer.

Comment: Close as duplicate is the appropriate thing to do.

Comment: This is not a duplicate as this question asks also how to ignore keyboard events and that's more complicated than what is done in that *duplicate*.

Comment: @TLama: Is it? Keyboard input will go to the focused control, which is seldom the transparent form (click it and you lose focus!), and maybe never if you also specify `WS_EX_NOACTIVATE`. Is this not true?

Comment: @Andreas, you can't focus the window by a click and it's not focused after its creation, but at least on Windows 7 with Delphi XE3 app I was able to focus the application ('s main form) from taskbar (the same I've reproduced with `MainFormOnTaskbar` on False with Delphi 2009 app). And you can also focus the application ('s main form) if you in *Task Manager* right click your app (on the first tab) and use the *Bring to front* feature. I don't know how to prevent the application could ever be focused.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the procedure BlockInput of USER32.DLL

You can try this (with caution!):

```
procedure Bloqued(block:boolean);
var
  milib: THandle;
  BlockInput : function(Block: BOOL): BOOL; stdcall;
begin
  milib := GetModuleHandle('USER32.DLL');
  if milib <> 0 then begin
    @BlockInput := GetProcAddress(milib, 'BlockInput');
    if @BlockInput <> nil then begin
       BlockInput(block);
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject) ;
begin
  Bloqued(true);
  Sleep(1000);
  Bloqued(false);
end;
```

Version without dinamic loading:

```
Function BlockInput (Block: BOOL): BOOL; stdcall; External 'USER32.DLL';

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  BlockInput(true);
  Sleep(1000);
  BlockInput(false);
end;
```

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to use dynamic loading here.

Comment: Added version without dinamic loading. Thanks @ Andreas Rejbrand for your suggestion.