# Problems when drawing a frame around a window

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-10.4-sydney

In a Delphi 10.4.2 Win32 VCL Application in Windows 10, I try to draw a frame around a window(-control):

```
procedure FrameWindow(aHandle: HWND);
var
  Rect: TRect;
  DC: Winapi.Windows.HDC;
  OldPen, Pen: Winapi.Windows.HPEN;
  OldBrush, Brush: Winapi.Windows.HBRUSH;
  X2, Y2: Integer;
begin
  { Get the target window's rect and DC }
  Winapi.Windows.GetWindowRect(aHandle, Rect);
  DC := Winapi.Windows.GetWindowDC(aHandle);
  { Set ROP appropriately for highlighting }
  Winapi.Windows.SetROP2(DC, R2_NOT);
  { Select brush and pen }
  Pen := Winapi.Windows.CreatePen(PS_InsideFrame, 3, 0);
  OldPen := Winapi.Windows.SelectObject(DC, Pen);
  Brush := Winapi.Windows.GetStockObject(Null_Brush);
  OldBrush := Winapi.Windows.SelectObject(DC, Brush);
  { Set dimensions of highlight }
  X2 := Rect.Right - Rect.Left;
  Y2 := Rect.Bottom - Rect.Top;
  { Draw highlight box }
  Rectangle(DC, 0, 0, X2, Y2);
  { Clean up }
  SelectObject(DC, OldBrush);
  SelectObject(DC, OldPen);
  ReleaseDC(aHandle, DC);
  { Do NOT delete the brush, because it was a stock object }
  DeleteObject(Pen);
end;
```

(When the FrameWindow procedure is called a second time with the same window handle, then the frame is erased).

This works well with controls on a window:

[image]

The FrameWindow procedure is called periodically to draw a new frame when the window handle (`Target.WindowHandle`) under the cursor changes and the old frame needs to be erased:

```
{ To avoid flickering, remove the old frame ONLY if moved to a new window }
if Target.WindowHandle <> FOldWindowHandle then
begin
  if FOldWindowHandle <> 0 then
    FrameWindow(FOldWindowHandle); // remove the old frame
  if Target.WindowHandle <> 0 then
    FrameWindow(Target.WindowHandle); // create new frame
  FOldWindowHandle := Target.WindowHandle; // remember new frame
end;
```

Problem #1: This works only for controls on a window, not for the whole window (e.g., when the mouse cursor is over the title bar of Notepad), although the window handle for the whole window is correct: No frame is drawn around the whole window.

Problem #2: Sometimes the frame is corrupted:

[image]

Problem #3: How can I set the frame color to red instead of black?

How to solve these problems?

Comment: You cannot reliably render into a device context you do not own.

Comment: @IInspectable What does this mean? How can I become the owner of the DC?

Comment: You cannot *"become"* the owner of a DC. You either own it (say, because you created it, or requested one from a window you own), or not own it. There is no going from the latter to the former. You're going to have to create a window if you wish to render to the display.

Comment: @IInspectable So you say that the redraw problems cannot be avoided with this procedure?

Comment: No, I'm saying that there is no reliable way to perform **any** rendering into a device context you do not own. There is no way for you to communicate to the DC's owner, that, *"hey look, I just used up some of YOUR screen space for MY purposes, surely you don't mind"*, and consequently there is no way for the owner to care. When it determines that things need to be redrawn, it will just go ahead and redraw things.

Comment: @IInspectable That sounds convincing. So would it be better to create a device context I own myself for the entire desktop over all the windows and then draw on that? For example: `with TCanvas.Create do Handle := GetDCEx(0, 0, DCX_WINDOW or DCX_CACHE);`

Comment: The question is, what do you want to achieve and why? There might be a better way to achieve what you want. If you want to highlight part of another window by drawing the frame, you could create a own window with your app that you just move to the correct position. That window could be partly transparent. If you have to be able to click through that window you could use regions and SetWindowRgn to create a window that just shaped like the frame you want to draw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have completely given up the idea to draw on the desktop. Now I use a TRANSPARENT CLICK-THROUGH window and place it over the target window:

[image]

```
Here is the source code of the form unit:

unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, System.Classes, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Panel1: TPanel;
    Panel2: TPanel;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  protected
    procedure CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams); override;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Win: HWND;
  R: TRect;
  offset: Integer;
begin
  Win := 135642;
  GetWindowRect(Win, R);
  offset := Panel2.Margins.Bottom;
  InflateRect(R, offset, offset);
  Self.BoundsRect := R;
  Self.Left := R.Left;
  Self.Top := R.Top;
end;

procedure TForm1.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11809973/click-through-transparent-form
begin
  inherited;
  Params.ExStyle := Params.ExStyle or WS_EX_LAYERED or WS_EX_TRANSPARENT;
end;

end.
```

And here is the DFM code:

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  AlphaBlend = True
  BorderStyle = bsNone
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 378
  ClientWidth = 589
  Color = clGreen
  TransparentColor = True
  TransparentColorValue = clGreen
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  FormStyle = fsStayOnTop
  OldCreateOrder = False
  Position = poDefault
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object Panel1: TPanel
    Left = 0
    Top = 0
    Width = 589
    Height = 378
    Align = alClient
    BevelOuter = bvNone
    Color = clRed
    ParentBackground = False
    TabOrder = 0
    ExplicitLeft = 200
    ExplicitTop = 224
    ExplicitWidth = 185
    ExplicitHeight = 41
    object Panel2: TPanel
      AlignWithMargins = True
      Left = 3
      Top = 3
      Width = 583
      Height = 372
      Align = alClient
      BevelOuter = bvNone
      Color = clGreen
      ParentBackground = False
      ShowCaption = False
      TabOrder = 0
      ExplicitLeft = 200
      ExplicitTop = 176
      ExplicitWidth = 185
      ExplicitHeight = 41
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score -5):

Sorry i cant comment yet. But if you want to draw in another application there is something like a Hook for Learning Programms. I cant remember it´s name. And i am not sure if it´s this: [CBTHookEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644977(v=vs.85))

I think i used something like this around 2001 to keep track of a Application to draw around it for a Learning Experience. But it seems to be outdatet. Perhaps someone has also an idear or even better a snippet.